# Need Column Name from input table in SSIS variable

Tags: ms-access, ssis

I am using SSIS to import data from an Access database created by another department.  It is weekly data, and one column is named [weeknum]_Sales - where each week the name of this column changes (201810_Sales, 201811_Sales, etc.)  I am mapping that column (by position) to column in my db (Sales) but I need to put "weeknum" in another column.

Basically, their database is aggregating sales by item, and has this week's total (table has all items but only one week), but my db has years of data.

Their table (in Access)
Store, UPC, Sales, Units.....

My table:
Store, WeekNum, UPC, Sales, Units....

So I need to "retrieve" the left 6 characters of column name of column 3 (or 4) to a variable or expression before the SSIS Dataflow runs, and set column 3 of my table to that value for all rows inserted.

I know how to set the the destination column to a literal, expression or variable - but I don't know the specifics of how to get the column's name at run time of the SSIS package.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you wold need to create a function that  modifies the SQL of a  pre-built query. You could run that function on a weekly basis in a scheduled task